# Angular 2 change array value on subscribe

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I want to change some values in an array after I subscribe to it.

```
this.data = this.search.getProductsById(this.id).subscribe
    ((data: any) => {
        this.list = data;
        //Here for each price I want to change price value 
        for (let entry of this.list.deals.new) {
            if (entry.country == 'UK') {
                let p = entry.price * 1.10837; //here I change price
                console.log(p); //displays new price
            }
        }
        this.loading = true;
    });
```

But in `HTML` it displays old price, not `p`. How to change it so I would get in `html` new one ?

Comment: Can you add your `html` code?

Comment: Your example doesn't show you aren't updating the price. By using `let` you are creating a new variable and aren't assigning it to anything. Changing the value would be done by doing something like `entry.price = entry.price * 1.10837;`

Comment: Sure, will edit right now.

Comment: Oh... Sorry for dumb question, really messed up... ;D

Comment: As @AndrėjusLazauskas said, you are just changing it locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because you didn't set the new value `p` in your array, i think it's like this:

```
this.data =  this.search.getProductsById(this.id).subscribe
((data: any) => {
    this.list = data;
//Here for each price I want to change price value 
   for(let entry of this.list.deals.new){
     if(entry.country == 'UK'){
      entry.price *= 1.10837;
      console.log(entry.price); //displays new price
     }
   }
    this.loading = true;
}
```

Comment: Yes... Sometimes just dumb mistakes.. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, your method getProductsById() return an array of deals which have country field. If I understand correctly, you should use [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) operator something like this

```
this.data = this.search.getProductsById(this.id)
.pipe(map((data: any) => {
  if (data.deals.country === 'UK') {
    return data.deals.price = data.deals.price * 1.10837;
  }
}))
.subscribe(data => console.log(data.deals.price));
```

For better understanding give us the structure of the returned object

Answer (score 1):

Your `p` is local to your `if` condition in a class only. You simply need to assign the value to the variable property itself.

So, just **replace the line `let p = entry.price * 1.10837;` with `entry.price = entry.price * 1.10837;`** That's it!